# What is the difference between javax.inject.Inject and com.google.inject.Inject?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, inject

I'm initiating myself to Google Guice.

I have a simple question :

What is the difference between the `javax.inject`'s `@Inject` annotation and the `com.google.inject`'s `@Inject` one ?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `org.jboss.beans.metadata.api.annotations.Inject`'s `@Inject`? :p

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`javax.inject` is a specification derived from google's work (and others)

Difference can be found in [Google Guice Wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330)